# custom datamap of the Netherlands in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, datamaps

I want to add a datamap of the Netherlands with provinces to my website. However I never worked with custom datamaps before. I believe I have the correct [data](http://www.webuildinternet.com/articles/2015-07-19-geojson-data-of-the-netherlands/provinces.geojson) format (geoJSON). I saved this by copying it into notepad and saving as geo_netherlands.json.

I tried loading the datamap like this:

```
var map = new Datamap({
    element: document.getElementById('map_netherlands'),
    geographyConfig: {
        dataUrl: 'data/geo_netherlands.json'
    }
});
```

resulting in

```
TypeError: a is null
```

What does this mean? Should I give more parameters when calling the Datamap, is the json file not good?

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle with linked d3.js and json data?

Comment: Actually, your JSON data is messed up, look this http://www.webuildinternet.com/articles/2015-07-19-geojson-data-of-the-netherlands/provinces.geojson

It's wrong, it's supposed to be like this: http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp

Comment: Oh wow such a silly mistake: Datamaps will attempt to fetch that resource as TopoJSON. I converted my geoJSON to topoJSON using this: http://jeffpaine.github.io/geojson-topojson/. I will let you know if that fixed it.

Comment: I made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L767kzpy/1/). Doesn't work yet :(

Comment: It seems it's missing lib due to datamap is not defined, besides you have set up wrong in jsfiddle, I 've fixed it BUT this is not answer, what a little more time to add CDN libraries for datamap https://jsfiddle.net/L767kzpy/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are very close, but there are a few more parameters you'll need to draw this map.

The first problem is you are using `dataUrl` but trying to access local data. You should actually use `dataJson` (undocumented).

Secondly you'll need to specify which geometry in the TopoJSON you want to use via the `scope` parameter. Looking at the TopoJSON you generated, that happens to be "collection".

You'll also want to give your container a width and a height so the map has some space to draw in (otherwise `height` defaults to 0 in HTML).

Lastly, you'll need a custom projection set up to focus the map on the Netherlands and zoom into it.

All put together, the JS looks like:

```
var map = new Datamap({
        element: document.getElementById('map_netherlands'),
        scope: "collection",
        geographyConfig: {
            dataJson: data
        },
       setProjection: function(element) {
       var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
         .scale(3000)
         .center([0, 52])
         .rotate([-4.8, 0])
         .translate([element.offsetWidth / 2, element.offsetHeight / 2]);
      var path = d3.geo.path()
         .projection(projection);

      return {path: path, projection: projection};
     },
    });
```

For more information on setting the project and generating custom data, I recommend: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/

I highly recommend you take a look at Bostock's post, especially where he generates the TopoJSON and specifies an `--id-property`, which will be necessary for you to target any particular district (to create a choropleth, for example).

The working JSFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/L767kzpy/4/

Comment: Where can I get the right values of `scale`, `center` and `rotate` for an specific land? if I already have the dataJson data.